# Copying from one workbook to another if it matches the criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy rows that satisfymy criteria from one workbook to another.

In my Workbook1, I want to look for 8TH Column, and if it has "TRU", then I would like to copy the entire to another new workbook with sheet name "Pivottable" and save it under .xlsx format.

I have tried the below code so far, but I am getting the error

> Subscript Out of Range

```
Sub OpenBook()
    Dim MyBook As Workbook, newBook As Workbook
    Dim FileNm As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set MyBook = ThisWorkbook

    FileNm = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "ProjectList.xlsx"
    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

    With MyBook
    With Worksheets("Pivottabelle")
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   End With
   End With

    With newBook
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "PivotTable"
    With Worksheets("PivotTable")
      j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   End With
   End With

   With newBook
   For i = 1 To LastRow
       With Worksheets("Pivottabelle")
           If .Cells(i, 8).Value = "TRU" Then
               .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("PivotTable").Range("A" & j)
               j = j + 1
           End If
       End With
   Next i

        'Save new wb with XLS extension
        .SaveAs Filename:=FileNm, FileFormat:=xlNormal, CreateBackup:=True

        .Close Savechanges:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Edit:
Error dialogue box
[image]

Comment: Care to tell us which line errors?

Comment: @SJR      
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "PivotTable" in this line

Comment: Your workbook With clauses do not have dots in front of the sheet references so probably VBA does not know to which book you are referring. `.Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "PivotTable"`

Comment: @SJR I want to assign that new workbook sheet1 to a new name called as Pivottable

Comment: All your sheet references refer to the active workbook (newBook by the looks of it). Even if that is not causing your error you should correct it.

Comment: @SJR     Now I am getting  a new error object variable or with not variable set in the line      With Sheets("Pivottabelle")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163852/discussion-between-mikz-and-sjr).

Comment: @SJR Could you please tell me , why I get a dialogue box in excel that says Compatibility check .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, there is a lot of use of `With` and `End With` here, without actually getting the benefit of it.

I've gone through the code and fixed it where I think it needed it but you might want to check that my interpretation is correct:

```
Dim FileNm As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Set MyBook = ThisWorkbook

FileNm = MyBook.Path & "\" & "ProjectList.xlsx"
Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

With MyBook.Worksheets("Pivottabelle")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With newBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Name = "PivotTable"
    j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With

With MyBook.Worksheets("Pivottabelle")
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If .Cells(i, 8).Value = "TRU" Then
            .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=newBook.Worksheets("PivotTable").Range("A" & j)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With

With newBook
    'Save new wb with XLS extension
    .SaveAs Filename:=FileNm, FileFormat:=xlNormal, CreateBackup:=True
    .Close Savechanges:=False
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for the clean code :) But there are some conditional formatting with cases in my Workbook that during pasting in new workbook, it opens a compatibility checker dialogue box and causes application defined error.

Comment: Your 'source' workbook is saved as an older version of Excel file. I'd suggest you save it and use the newly saved version first and always, before running any macros.

Comment: What fileformat are you saving the 'new' version as?

Comment: Okay. Now completely close the file and then reopen the new xlsm file.

Comment: I have edited my post with the error dialogue box. with new Xlsm file also happens the same

Comment: Oh, my bad. I haven't seen that one for a while now. Just untick the "Check compatibility when saving this workbook" checkbox (near the bottom of the pop-up) and this check will stop being performed.

Comment: I did that, and unfortunately it does not work, the next time I open my excel file. it says the file is corrupted and can not be opened

Comment: I'd suggest raising a new question for that, as it's off topic for your main question and doesn't really include VBA (although a workaround might)..

Comment: I would still accept your code as my answer as it had satisfied the question I posted